# Maximum amount of warnings exceeded. Use -maxwarnings to override

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, qtest

I'm running a big unit test based on QTest and during the test process, it's stopping with error:

`QSYSTEM: ClassXyzTest::xyzTest() Maximum amount of warnings exceeded. Use -maxwarnings to override.`

I've got some debugs in the code to have more information about operation progress etc., but I don't see warnings during compilation.

I tried set in **Project -> Command line arguments** argument `-maxwarnings 0` without success. 0 value should be unlimited - [More details](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html#testing-options)

Comment: Try to compile Qt example from: Welcome -> Examples -> Chapter 1: Writing a Unit Test. It should work when you set: Projects -> Run Settings -> Command line arguments to "-maxwarnings 0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [`QTest::qExec`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#qExec) function to run your test, make sure that you are passing arguments from your test app's `main` function to the `QTest::qExec`.

```
int main(argc, char **argv)
{
    MyTestObject test1;
    QTest::qExec(&test1, argc, argv);
}
```